# Is this entrance exam question correct regarding uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, contest-math, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> Q. Consider the sequence of real-valued functions $\{f_n\}$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\frac {1}{1+nx^2}.$$ Assuming the fact that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function  $f$ find out real numbers $x$ for which $$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f'_n(x).$$

Here each $f_n$ is a continuous function. If the sequence $f_n$ were to converge uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ must have been continuous too. But  $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$ is discontinuous.

Am I making mistakes here? I am not able to comprehend this question.

Comment: The question would be less weird with 2) on what interval does $f_n'$ converge and what is the limit ?

Comment: You are correct - $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$, since the limit function is discontinuous. Perhaps the domain should instead be e.g. $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Math1000 Can we say that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$?

Comment: No. Consider the sequence $f_n\left(\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: @Math1000 This applies to $(0,\infty)$ also. So our domain must be $(-\infty,-a) \cup (a,\infty)$ for any $a \gt 0$.